# How to securely transfer cookies between two domains?

Tags: cookies, web, data-transfer

Let's say you have a website https://example.org which is being decommissioned and redirected to https://example.net.

Your users have a cookie on https://example.org which contains some authentication token for the backend services (e.g. https://backend.example.org). You want the redirect on https://example.org to also transfer this token to a cookie on https://example.net.

Without asking the user to reauthenticate, what is the best way to securely transfer this?

Comment: Bite the bullet and have users reauthenticate. The burden of them having to type their credentials in again is minimal in comparison to maintaining and testing any system you could come up with.

Comment: mti2935's answer is correct, but tbh you prob dont even need to go that far.  While it is not best practice to use the URL string to xfer data it is encrypted the same way cookies and header information is.  You could base64 encode the entire cookie and put it in the URL string if you wanted too. Though I would do it through an api call such that it didn't show up in the address bar to prevent it being copied and pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines might work:

1. Generate an AES encryption key, known to https://example.org and https://example.net.
2. On the initial request by the user to https://example.org, the server encrypts timestamp|authentication token using the key, then responds with a 301 rediect to https://example.net?xxxxx (where xxxxx is the ciphertext).
3. On the request to https://example.net?xxxxx, the server uses the key to decrypt xxxxx to get timestamp|authentication token.  The server checks that timestamp is not more than n seconds in the past (to avoid replay attacks).  If so, the server authenticates the user stores the authentication token in a cookie for https://example.net.

Comment: If AES is used, make sure to use a variant that allows for message authentication (e.g. AES-GCM), else the plaintext can often be modified.

Comment: This answer is not wrong. But the fact that users remain authenticated over a long time means a more serious security problem than securely transferring cookies to another site.

Comment: @mentallurg https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2023/08/16/session-timeout/

Comment: 1) @CaffeineAddiction: The linked article contains some wrong statements. E.g. it is speaking about reauthentication and login every 15 minutes. This has nothing to do with reality. If application uses refresh token, user does not have to login frequently.

Comment: 2) "Session tokens are pretty secure." - This is abstract statement without any value. One should consider the entire application architecture. Without knowing how the application addresses CSRF and XSS, and if at all, and without knowing how exactly session tokens are implemented, it is impossible to say if session tokens are secure or not.

Comment: 3) "if someone compromises your session, you’re screwed whether it lasts five minutes or for ever" - Nope. Namely short living tokens force the attacker to use them immediately. Where as long living tokens allow the attacker to abuse them over the long time and allow to stay unnoticed. E.g. instead of transferring a big amount of money that can be blocked or will be at least noticed as suspicious, the attacker can do small transfers over a long time, that will not be blocked and will not be even noticed over a long time.

Comment: 4) The article mentions Google and Microsoft. But for instance SSID and HSID are HttpOnly, which essentially reduces security risks. The article doesn't say any word about that.

Comment: 5) The article mentions Google and Microsoft, but it doesn't say any word that they use much more tools for security. E.g. they use device fingerprinting, user behavior profiles, etc. That's why they not only can allow long session timeouts, but they can even allow simple short passwords. Where as an average company cannot afford such security measures.

Comment: All in all: The good thing in the article is that it animates readers not to blindly apply any rules, but first think about them. The bad thing is that the author presents his opinion as the obvious truth.